# How can we still see the CMB?

Tags: cosmology, visible-light, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

May seem stupid but i cant wrap my head around it. if a star explodes we eventually see it when the light gets here. but once its got here we see the event and the star is now gone, we cant see it anymore because its not there anymore. so how can we still see the CMB if all the light has reached us, why can we continue to see it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will the CMB ever stop shining?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129632/)

Comment: Also see https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Glossary/Essay_lss.html & https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March03/Lineweaver/Lineweaver7_2.html

Answer (score 7):

The CMB happened everywhere in the universe. As time goes on we see it from further and further away.